# Who is the unidentified character in this photo of dead characters from The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead, character-identification, actors

[image]

I was able to identify all but one of the people in this photo of actors who played characters who are now dead on the show.  I can't figure out who the last one is - Randall?  Gareth?  Someone else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [the original article](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/02/11/walking-dead-reunion-deceased-characters) featuring the image; it's Sam, played by Robin Lord Taylor (emphasis mine):

> We gathered these unlucky souls together to pay tribute to their characters and time on the show while they were in Orlando, FL last June at a Walker Stalker convention, and the result is the photo you see below.
>
> Included from left to right are Madison Lintz (Sophia), Kyla Kenedy (Mika), Jeryl Prescott (Jacqui), Brighton Sharbino (Lizzie), Chad L. Coleman (Tyreese), Tyler James Williams (Noah), David Morrissey (The Governor), Emily Kinney (Beth), IronE Singleton (T-Dog), Lawrence Gilliard Jr. (Bob), and **Robin Lord Taylor (Sam)**.

It's easy to forget him, because he's changed his hair since leaving the show (presumably for *Gotham*, where Taylor plays the Penguin):

[image]

Comment: HIPPIE SAM!  Of course!  I didn't recognize him because of the hair.

Comment: Good research! But wait what.. This guy is supposed to be a more memorable dead character than Shane, Lori, Jim, Andrea, Dale, Merle?

Comment: @Junuxx According to the linked article, the picture was taken at a con in Orlando last year. My working theory is that these are the people who just happened to be there